# Finding the largest number in a column using 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to write a method that finds the largest number in a column. However, it seems that I am having problem to  find a way to return the highest number in a column rather than taking into consideration all numbers combined in the array. I would really appreciate any comments or feedback!

This is my code:

```
public static void max1(int[][] score) {
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        int max = score[0][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < score[i].length; j++)
            if (score[i][j] > max)
                max = score[i][j];
        System.out.println(max + "      ");
    }
}
```

Comment: start by taking column number as input parameter. You need only one loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `int max = score[0][i];` instead of `int max = score[0][0];` Because if you always intialize max with `score[0][0]` and this int is bigger then the biggest value in a column, you will get a wrong result.

And do:

```
         if (score[innerloop][outerloop] > max)
            max = score[innerloop][outerloop];
```

instead of:

```
        if (score[outerloop][innerloop] > max)
            max = score[outerloop][innerloop];
```

That was logical failure because the first index is the column and the secound is the row.

```
    score[0][0] = 1;
    score[0][1] = 2;
    score[0][2] = 3;
    score[1][0] = 4;
    score[1][1] = 5;
    score[1][2] = 6;
    score[2][0] = 7;
    score[2][1] = 8;
    score[2][2] = 9;
```

The Array now look like this matrix:

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6 
 7 8 9
```

You want compare for example 1,4,7 so you habe to compare `score[0][0]`, `score[0][1]`, `score[0][2]`. So the secound index must be the counter of the inner for-loop.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to find the max in row not in column. Do some changes in your code

```
public static void max1(int[][] score) {
    for (int i = 0; i < score[0].length; i++) { // i should be your column
        int max = score[0][i];// assign 1st value of the column as max
        for (int j = 0; j < score.length; j++){ // j is your row
            if (score[j][i] > max){ // check the column elements instead of row elements
                max = score[j][i];// get the column values 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max + "      ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the index of the column you want to find the max in and loop on rows:

```
public static int maxCol(int [][] score, int colIndex) {
    int max = score[0][colIndex];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < score.length ; ++i) {
        max = Math.max(max, score[i][colIndex]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should change the `int max = score[0][0];` into as `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` as it might produce not valid result.

And the second is that you need to swap the index while compare

```
 if (score[j][i] > max) {
        max = score[j][i];
 }
```

Comment: it should be `score[0][i]` instead

Comment: As we are interested in columns you have right but we risk index out of bound exception with that.

Comment: Vash is right, you have to set max to the lowest value possible for the initialisation else this could generate some really bad errors later!

Comment: That's better and more safe idea indeed

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void max1(int[][] score) {
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        int max = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < score[i].length; j++)
            if (score[i][j] > max)
                max = score[i][j];
        System.out.println("max: '" + max + "'");
    }
}
```

**And perhaps you switched your columns and rows, means you have to switch the code too, happened already a lot to me.** Try to check if i is your rows and j is your columns.

Answer (score 1):

The following code prints the Maximum Number in each column.

```
public static void max1(int[][] score) {
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // set max to minimum value before starting loop
        for (int j = 0; j < score[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (score[i][j] > max)
                max = score[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println(max + "      ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int max1(int[][] score) {
    int max = score[0][0]; // set initial value to the first index in array
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) { // cycle through row
        for (int j = 0; j < score[i].length; j++) { // cycle through colmn
            if (score[i][j] > max) { // if the index value is greater than largest number
                max = score[i][j]; // make it the new index value
            }
        }
    } return max;
}
```