# Finding the maximum integer value contained in a matrix using Java

Tags: java, matrix, integer, max

To find the maximum integer value in a matrix I try to code some of that:

```
/*
 * @param ints
 * @return the max value in the array of chars
 */

public static int maxMatrix(int [][] ints) {
    int max = ints[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < ints.length){
            max = inst[i][j];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

My questions are:

- Why am I assigning the variable to the next one in the array?
- What are the conditions and why?

Comment: This is not code review ! FYI what you are doing is wrong. You haven't check if the value is greater or not.

Comment: Nope. You're just assigning `max`  with the value of each 2-dimension array.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064558/finding-the-largest-number-in-a-column-using-2d-arrays

Comment: Why do I still have negative votes on this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max = inst[i][j];`

Should be `max = Math.max(max, ints[i][j]);`

and...

`for(int j = 0; j < ints.length){`

should be `for(int j = 0; j < ints[i].length; j++){`

So...

```
public static int maxMatrix(int [][] ints) {
    int max = ints[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < ints[i].length; j++){
            max = Math.max(max, ints[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

You need to do Math.max.  Otherwise you're just assigning the variable to the next in the array

Math.max(max, ints[i][j]) is equivalent to:

```
if (max > ints[i][j] {
  return ints[i][j];  // or inline in your loop: max = ints[i][j];
} else {
  return max;         // or inline in your loop: max = max; which is a not needed
}
```

Comment: Way does the `max = Math.max(max, inst[i][j]);` should be like that?

Comment: See my edit.  Math.max returns the largest of the two variables

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this

```
    for (int[] a : ints) {
        for (int e : a) {
            if (e > max) {
                max = e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an if statement inside of your loop for that to work.  Also you need to check the length of the second part of the array.

```
public static int maxMatrix(int [][] ints) {
int max = ints[0][0];

for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < ints[].length){
        if(inst[i][j] > max){
            max = inst[i][j];
        }
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```